# Descartar campos vacíos en formulario get

Tags: formularios

Tengo un formulario multicampo de búsqueda get.

La url pasa datos de título, tema, categoría, fecha, etc.

```
index.php?s=&a=&t=&i=&cat=2&r=&f=
```

Quiero descartar los campos vacíos. Al ser una búsqueda multicampo el usuario puede escoger poner tema, fecha, palabra en título. Parece ser que los campos vacíos afectan la búsqueda y la hace imprecisa ¿Por qué?, Entonces quiero que si están vacíos no se incluyan en el `get`

No entiendo bien cómo hacerlo dentro del formulario.

Comment: Al parecer estás trabajando con PHP, lo que podrías hacer es filtrar si el dato enviado por get está vacío. Puedes usar la función `empty` (`!empty` para negar que esté vacío), ejemplo: `if(!empty($_GET['dato'])){//Acciones a realizar}`

Comment: así es, ya estuve checando esa función, pero cómo ponerla dentro del formulario, es lo que no encuentro.

Comment: Suponiendo que en el formulario hay un campo que se llame `descripcion`, ese dato se enviará por GET, cuando se reciba el dato hay que verificar que no esté vacío, ejemplo: `if(!empty($_GET['descripcion'])){echo $_GET['descripcion'];}else{echo "No ha enviado nada";}`

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que quieres necesitas utilizar jQuery / js:

```
$('#id_del_formulario').submit(function () {
    $(this)
        .find('input[name]')
        .filter(function () {
            return !this.value;
        })
        .prop('name', '');
});
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029532/how-to-prevent-submitting-the-html-forms-input-field-value-if-it-empty)

Comment: parece buena idea, ya la apliqué pero sigue apareciendo el get del input name especificado

Comment: <form method="get" id="searchform3" action=" ">

<input type="text"  name="a" id="a" maxlenght="200" align="middle" size="30" value="">

<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value=""  onClick="submitForm()" >

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitForm() {
  $('#searchform3').submit(function () {
  $(this)
          .find("input[name='a']")
         .filter(function () {
             return !this.value;
         })
          .prop('name', '');
 });
 }
</script>

Comment: Es código jquery, supongo que tienes puesto el link de la libreria en el <head> ?

Comment: si lo tiene <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: Prueba a sacarlo fuera de submitForm, y a quitar la llamada a submitForm desde onclick="" <script>$('#searchform3').submit(function () { $(this) .find("input[name='a']") .filter(function () { return !this.value; }) .prop('name', ''); });</script>

Comment: lamentablemente no funciona. seguiré investigando